# Google translate remove arrow in IE

Tags: jquery, html, css, internet-explorer-7, google-translate

Im looking to remove the arrow from the google translate button, no matter what i do, i can't remove it from IE7 or IE8 and its making me go crazy.

Image of the arrow below:

[image: arrow in google translate]

I've been able to style the rest of the translate but this arrow isn't going anywhere. code im using for Chrome and FF is:

```
div#google_translate_element div.goog-te-gadget-simple a.goog-te-menu-value span:last-child
```

Im running modernizr and all the other things to add support for last child. All the HTML is valid so no querks mode is being activated. I can't even target it with jquery. Its so weird.

Any help would be awesome.

sorry should have added this in, this is what google wants you to put into the page:

```
    <div id="google_translate_element"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
                                                    function googleTranslateElementInit() {
                                                      new google.translate.TranslateElement({pageLanguage: 'en', includedLanguages: 'de,es,fr,pl,zh-CN,zh-TW', layout: google.translate.TranslateElement.InlineLayout.SIMPLE, multilanguagePage: true}, 'google_translate_element');
                                                    }
                                                    </script><script type="text/javascript" src="//translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit"></script>
```

and then this is what it spits out:

```
<div id="google_translate_element">
<div class="skiptranslate goog-te-gadget" dir="ltr" style="">
<div id=":0.targetLanguage" class="goog-te-gadget-simple" style="white-space: nowrap;">
<img src="http://www.google.com/images/cleardot.gif" class="goog-te-gadget-icon" style="background-image: url(http://translate.googleapis.com/translate_static/img/te_ctrl3.gif); background-position: -65px 0px;">
<span style="vertical-align: middle;">
    <a class="goog-te-menu-value" href="javascript:void(0)">
    <span>Select Language</span>
    <img src="http://www.google.com/images/cleardot.gif" width="1" height="1">
    <span style="border-left-width: 1px; border-left-style: solid; border-left-color: rgb(187, 187, 187);">&#8203;</span>
    <img src="http://www.google.com/images/cleardot.gif" width="1" height="1">
    <span style="color: rgb(155, 155, 155);">▼</span>
    </a>
</span>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

and its the last span im trying to target:

```
<span style="color: rgb(155, 155, 155);">▼</span>
```

Comment: Can we get some markup so we know what we're working with?

Comment: have edited to post to include. Sorry didn't include first time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the code being generated will never change, you could do it like this:

```
#google_translate_element span[style="color: rgb(155, 155, 155);"] {
    display:none;
}
```

That does seem quite a big hack though -- if you're loading this code direct from Google, there's no predicting that they might change their code in some subtle way and break your selector.

Using `#google_translate_element a>span:last-child` as the selector might be a more "correct" way to do it, but even that is subject to Google deciding to change the layout of their widget. Pretty much any selector you try to use to get to this element is going to have the same problem on that score.

Another angle to approach might be to use javascript to find and replace the down-arrow character from the string. Maybe something like this:

```
$("#google_translate_element a span").each(function() {
    $(this).html($(this).html().replace(/▼/,""));
});
```

Using `each()` here so that I can avoid having to be too specific with the selector, to avoi the issues described above.

And I know that looks like a long-winded way of doing it, but I'm trying to avoid breaking any event handlers. Otherwise I could just have done:

```
document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(/▼/,"");
```

But that would break stuff if you were using event handlers because it would rebuild the whole DOM, so use the `each()` method instead to do the replacement globally like that.

Comment: These seem right, and i'd use these but the problem seems to be that it loads after the document. So a set timeout removes it. Thank you for these.

i used this:

setTimeout(function() {
       $('#google_translate_element .goog-te-gadget-simple span a.goog-te-menu-value span:last-child').hide();
 }, 500);

Answer (score 0):

ie7 and 8 don't understand last-child...if i were you i'd insert javascript via conditional comments target ie8 and below, then remove/hide the element. jQuery would be easiest, and you can use the jQuery last-child selector

Comment: Im also running selectizr with dom assist which adds support for :last-child when running with jQuery. Its not so much a CSS problem. It wont even let me find the suspect span with jquery.

Comment: you're going to want to wait to fire it off until after the google script loads. you can wrap it in an if statement checking to make sure the element exists using .length() like so: $('#googleElement').length

Answer (score -1):

I did it this way and it worked fine:

```
 #google_translate_element select{
  /*to remove arrow:*/
  appearance: none;
   }
```